# Limiting choices for ForeignKey field to instance variables in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I created a Match model for a tournament related application (Team is just another model):

```
class Match(models.Model):
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="home_team", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="away_team", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    winning_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="winning_team", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My question is, is it possible to limit the choices for the winning_team field to only be either home_team or away_team? i.e. If I create a form to record the team that won, how can I limit the choices in that select list to just home_team and away_team?

Comment: read foreignkey limit choices_to:
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off making `winning_team` a simple choice between "home_team" and "away_team"; if you need to, you could then add a property to get the actual winning team dependent on the value of that field. For example:

```
WINNERS = (
  ('H', 'Home team'),
  ('A', 'Away team'),
)
class Match(models.Model):
    ...
    winners = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=WINNERS)

    @property
    def winning_team(self):
        return self.home_team if self.winners == 'H' else self.away_team
```